# How to quantify the asymmetry of an image using openCV or something else?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

Now I have two images:

[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LuxG.png), [Figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85gTT.png)

We can see that Figure 1 shows obviously asymmetry while Figure 2 is totally symmetric. Now I would like to quantify the asymmetry of Figure 1. Is there any reliable and elegant to do so? These images are grids plotted using pylab.contourf, I would like to extract the  parameters describing asymmetry, to find its relation with some physics properties.

The solution in python will be the best.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-quantify-the-asymmetry-of-an-image/6508

Comment: Maybe [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15916/how-to-quantify-asymmetry-of-a-signal) could be helpful. Regarding your figures, it could be possible to discretize the different color layers into multiple curves and calculate their respective functions. Then, you can use the answer @Jazzmaniac provides.